# How to transform/filter items on sublist?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

My form returns a sublist with check boxes, but I am unable to filter the added field and checkboxes (to submit and transform). The form has added fields and the filtered sublist at the bottom. How would I :

1. Add additional filters after clicking the filter button. Similar to : `var trandate = '&trandate='+nlapiGetFieldValue('custpage_trandate');`.
2. Transform the selected checked transactions after clicking the submit button.

Form has `addField`, pages, and sublist. It is similar to the link below, but I am unable to understand, as it is written in Suitescript 1.0 and the 2.0 version as [the example returns an error](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/89356/kw/form%20filter%20suitescript%202).

The code to explain what I have and would like to do:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */

var PAGE_SIZE = 20;
var SEARCH_ID = 'customsearch1160';
var CLIENT_SCRIPT_FILE_ID = 9836;

define(['N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/search', 'N/redirect'],
    function (serverWidget, search, redirect) {
    function onRequest(context) {
        if (context.request.method == 'GET') {
            var form = serverWidget.createForm({
                    title : 'Unbilled Orders',
                    hideNavBar : false
                });

            form.clientScriptFileId = CLIENT_SCRIPT_FILE_ID;
            form.addField({
                id: 'trandate_criteria',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.DATE,
                label: 'Transaction Date',
                source: 'trandate'
            });
            var customer_field = form.addField({
                id : 'name_criteria',
                label : 'Name',
                type : serverWidget.FieldType.MULTISELECT,
                source: 'customer'
            });
            // form.addField({
            //     id : 'orderno_criteria',
            //     label : 'Document No.',
            //     type : serverWidget.FieldType.MULTISELECT,
            //     source: 'transaction'
            // });
            form.addField({
                id : 'orderno_criteria', 
                label : 'Document No.',
                type : serverWidget.FieldType.MULTISELECT,
                source: 'transaction'
            });
            form.addField({
            id : 'location_criteria',
            label : 'Location',
            type : serverWidget.FieldType.MULTISELECT,
            source: 'location'
            });
            var statusA = form.addField({
            id : 'status_criteria',
            label : 'Status',
            type : serverWidget.FieldType.MULTISELECT,
            source: 'status'
            });
            statusA.addSelectOption({
                value :'Pending Billing', text :'Pending Billing'});
            statusA.addSelectOption({
                value :'Pending Billing/Partially Fulfilled', text :'Pending Billing/Partially Fulfilled'});
            var buttonSubmit = form.addSubmitButton({
                label: 'Submit'
                });
            var buttonFilter = sublist.addButton({
                label: 'Filter',
                id: 'custpage_mybutton',
                functionName: 'myButtonFunction'
                });
            // Get parameters
            var pageId = parseInt(context.request.parameters.page);
            var scriptId = context.request.parameters.script;
            var deploymentId = context.request.parameters.deploy;

            // Add sublist that will show results
            var sublist = form.addSublist({
                    id : 'custpage_table',
                    type : serverWidget.SublistType.LIST,
                    label : 'Orders to Bill'
                });
                sublist.addMarkAllButtons();
                sublist.addRefreshButton();     
                sublist.addField({
                    id : 'custpage_id',
                    label : 'Check',
                    type : serverWidget.FieldType.CHECKBOX
                   }).updateDisplayType({displayType: serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.ENTRY});
                   
            // Add columns to be shown on Page
            sublist.addField({
                id : 'id',
                label : 'Internal ID',
                type : serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT
            });

            // sublist.addField({
            //     id : 'amount',
            //     label : 'Amount',
            //     type : serverWidget.FieldType.CURRENCY
            // });
            sublist.addField({
                id: 'tran_id',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
                label: 'Document No.'
                });
            sublist.addField({
                id: 'trandate_id',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
                label: 'Transaction Date'
                });
            sublist.addField({
                id : 'name_id',
                label : 'Name',
                type : serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT
               });
               sublist.addField({
                id : 'location_id',
                label : 'Location',
                type : serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT
               });
               sublist.addField({
                id : 'amount_id',
                label : 'Amount',
                type : serverWidget.FieldType.CURRENCY
               });
               sublist.addField({
                id : 'status_id',
                label : 'Status',
                type : serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT
               });
            // Run search and determine page count
            var retrieveSearch = runSearch(SEARCH_ID, PAGE_SIZE);
            var pageCount = Math.ceil(retrieveSearch.count / PAGE_SIZE);

            // Set pageId to correct value if out of index
            if (!pageId || pageId == '' || pageId < 0)
                pageId = 0;
            else if (pageId >= pageCount)
                pageId = pageCount - 1;

            // Add buttons to simulate Next & Previous
            if (pageId != 0) {
                form.addButton({
                    id : 'custpage_previous',
                    label : 'Previous',
                    functionName : 'getSuiteletPage(' + scriptId + ', ' + deploymentId + ', ' + (pageId - 1) + ')'
                });
            }

            if (pageId != pageCount - 1) {
                form.addButton({
                    id : 'custpage_next',
                    label : 'Next',
                    functionName : 'getSuiteletPage(' + scriptId + ', ' + deploymentId + ', ' + (pageId + 1) + ')'
                });
            }

            // Add drop-down and options to navigate to specific page
            var selectOptions = form.addField({
                    id : 'custpage_pageid',
                    label : 'Page Index',
                    type : serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT
                });

            for (i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
                if (i == pageId) {
                    selectOptions.addSelectOption({
                        value : 'pageid_' + i,
                        text : ((i * PAGE_SIZE) + 1) + ' - ' + ((i + 1) * PAGE_SIZE),
                        isSelected : true
                    });
                } else {
                    selectOptions.addSelectOption({
                        value : 'pageid_' + i,
                        text : ((i * PAGE_SIZE) + 1) + ' - ' + ((i + 1) * PAGE_SIZE)
                    });
                }
            }

            // Get subset of data to be shown on page
            var addResults = fetchSearchResult(retrieveSearch, pageId);

            // Set data returned to columns
            var j = 0;
            addResults.forEach(function (result) {
                sublist.setSublistValue({
                    id : 'id',
                    line : j,
                    value : result.id
                });

                // sublist.setSublistValue({
                //     id : 'amount',
                //     line : j,
                //     value : result.amount
                // });
                            //SET VALUES
            sublist.setSublistValue({
                id : 'tran_id',
                line : j,
                value : result.tran_id
            });
            sublist.setSublistValue({
                id : 'trandate_id',
                line : j,
                value : result.trandate_id
            });
            sublist.setSublistValue({
                id : 'name_id',
                line : j,
                value : result.name_id
            });
            sublist.setSublistValue({
                id : 'location_id',
                line : j,
                value : result.location_id
            });
            sublist.setSublistValue({
                id : 'amount_id',
                line : j,
                value : result.amount_id
            });
            sublist.setSublistValue({
                id : 'status_id',
                line : j,
                value : result.status_id
            });

                j++;
            });

            context.response.writePage(form);
        }
        if (context.request.method == 'POST') {//POST
            //Get Select Field Value
            var delimiter = /\u0005/;
            var id_filter =context.request.parameters.id.split(delimiter);
            var date_filter =context.request.parameters.trandate_criteria.split(delimiter);
            var name_filter =context.request.parameters.name_field.split(delimiter);
            var orderNo_filter =context.request.parameters.orderno_criteria.split(delimiter);
            var location_filter =context.request.parameters.location_criteria.split(delimiter);
            var status_filter =context.request.parameters.status_criteria.split(delimiter);
            log.debug("tranid", orderNo);

    }

    return {
        onRequest : onRequest
    };

    function runSearch(searchId, searchPageSize) {
        var searchObj = search.load({
                id : searchId
            });

        log.debug('searchObj', JSON.stringify(searchObj));

        return searchObj.runPaged({
            pageSize : searchPageSize
        });
    }

    function fetchSearchResult(pagedData, pageIndex) {

        var searchPage = pagedData.fetch({
                index : pageIndex
            });

        var results = new Array();
        searchPage.data.forEach(function (result) {

            var internalId = result.id;
            var tran_id = result.getValue({name: 'tranid'});
            var trandate_id = result.getValue({name: 'trandate'});
            var name_id = result.getText({name: 'entity'});
            var location_id = result.getText({name: 'location'});
            var amount_id = result.getValue({name: 'amount'});
            var status_id = result.getText({name: 'statusref'});

            results.push({
                "id" : internalId,
                "tran_id" : tran_id,
                "trandate_id" : trandate_id,
                "name_id" : name_id,
                "location_id" : location_id,
                "amount_id" : amount_id,
                "status_id" : status_id
            });
        });
        return results;
    }

});
```

Client script:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(['N/url'],
    function (url) {
    function fieldChanged(context) {
        // Navigate to selected page
        if (context.fieldId == 'custpage_pageid') {
            var pageId = context.currentRecord.getValue({
                    fieldId : 'custpage_pageid'
                });

            pageId = parseInt(pageId.split('_')[1]);

            document.location = url.resolveScript({
                    scriptId : getParameterFromURL('script'),
                    deploymentId : getParameterFromURL('deploy'),
                    params : {
                        'page' : pageId
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    function getSuiteletPage(suiteletScriptId, suiteletDeploymentId, pageId) {
        document.location = url.resolveScript({
                scriptId : suiteletScriptId,
                deploymentId : suiteletDeploymentId,
                params : {
                    'page' : pageId
                }
            });
    }

    function getParameterFromURL(param) {
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var vars = query.split("&");
        for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            var pair = vars[i].split("=");
            if (pair[0] == param) {
                return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
            }
        }
        return (false);
    }

    return {
        fieldChanged : fieldChanged,
        getSuiteletPage : getSuiteletPage
    };

});
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have now and we can advise what is needed? I will say that what you can do is have a client script that triggers on your filter button (you can also just do fieldChanged and not have a button). POST in the Suitelet is when you process your "submit"

Comment: @TMann, I've added the codes I currently have. I'm still new to this and hopefully you could help? I've gotten as far as returning the search using a load., but not as far as filtering the data and doing something about it.

Comment: Chiming in; am interested to help. when you say transform, are you trying to use the `record.transform()` function at any point? Perhaps you could provide a screenshot as well? Would love to help, just need some more information if possible.

Comment: @zerecees Yes, would be using record.transform after the submit button depending on the selected sublist checkbox. So after selecting, we would reduce and transform the selected into either sales invoice or cash invoice using a try clause. (Actually made a map and reduce that does this but it was missing the initial steps of letting the user select the order.) If you could help would connecting the map and reduce would it be a better?

Comment: Potentially. I am still after the Suitelet at the moment, because I think you may be doing something counter-intuitive (no worries, I do it all the time). Are you trying to save the Suitelet to NetSuite somewhere, pick it up later, and THEN do `record.transform`? If so, what record are you saving the Suitelet to?

Comment: @zerecees, basically trying to invoicing order feature of netsuite, but includes the option to consolidate selected orders into one bill instead of individual bills.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm going to review your post again when I have more time to focus, as I certainly don't want to send you down the wrong path. Give me two days from now to do so. I promise I'll write back, I just need the proper time to wrap my head around this. Is that fair?

Comment: @zerecees Thank you! Any solution really helps.

Comment: @zerecees, did you get any luck transforming a few selected orders into one invoice?

Comment: Hi @MarthaF! I apologize as I have been having to focus my attention elsewhere lately. Unfortunately, I do not forsee myself having the availability I would need over the next few weeks to dive into this for you. I promise I will soon, but don't want to give a definite ETA to be misleading. If you wish to start off yourself, I recommend reading through the documentation on `record.transform` and `map/reduce` scripts. I am confident those will be good starting points, based upon my loose understanding of what you are trying to do. I will write back when I can!

Comment: @zerecees, I might have to figure out first how to call the selected orders first before the transform part as that is still the main problem. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. If you make some progress, do let me know! Unfortunately, I'm still having to focus on other things right now. But I do login and check once every few days. So, I'll be here!

Comment: Hi @zerecees, if you have time. Could you suggest on how to filter after a button click? I've posted in a separate question and hopefully you would have some insights. I've updated the codes in there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61730108/how-to-filter-sublist-based-on-addfield-suitescript  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up linking one suitelet to another.